# Xcode save a PDF as Image?

Tags: iphone, image

I have a question, is it possible to save a PDF to Camera Roll? I mean, I know how to save a Picture, but can you save a PDF as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to do it indirectly, and some one has tried it, you can't view it. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2479252

Camera Roll is for Photos.
iBooks is for PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

As @jshin47 - the following fragment will get you going:

This converts a pdf called test.pdf sitting in the local documents directory to a png called test.png. I've used A4 dimensions for the PDF, but if you're not in UK / Europe you might need to US letter sizes.

```
NSString* localDocuments = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfPath = [localDocuments stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];

// create a sample PDF (just for illustration)
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPath, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);
[@"Test string" drawInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 200) withFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 48.0]];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pdfPath];

CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL ((CFURLRef) url);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(596,842));
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 842);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0); // make sure the page is the right way up

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (document, 1); // first page of PDF is page 1 (not zero)
CGContextDrawPDFPage (currentContext, page);  // draws the page in the graphics context

UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSString* imagePath = [localDocuments stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: imagePath atomically:YES];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); // do error checking in production code
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working but the picture is only white..?

Comment: Most likely it can't find a valid PDF called 'test.pdf' in the documents folder. If url is nil - which it will be if it can't find the file, say - then it will just generate a blank PNG. I've added four lines to create a PDF and save it in the documents folder. If that generates an image OK, then the problem is most likely url not being the URL for a valid PDF file.

Comment: One question: that works perfect :) but how can ich use a pdf from the UIWebview (UIwebview.request.URL.absoluteString) and not from document folder?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible. Apple only allows Photos and Videos to be stored in the Photo Library. PDF formatted files can be stored in iBooks, or other programs that can handle PDF's but the Photo Library cannot accept PDF's

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the PDF into a set of images, and import those into the roll. You cannot add the actual PDF to the roll.

Comment: so how I can convert pdf to images?