# Convert PDF to PNG

Tags: iphone, image, pdf

I will convert a PDF with sometimes more then one pages to an PNG.

Actually I use this Code:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: pdfPath];

CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL ((CFURLRef) url);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(596,842));
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 842);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0); // make sure the page is the right way up

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (document, 1); // first page of PDF is page 1 (not zero)
CGContextDrawPDFPage (currentContext, page);  // draws the page in the graphics context

UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSString* imagePath = [localDocuments stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Karte.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: imagePath atomically:YES];
```

But this convert only the first page. Have any one an Idea how I can convert all pages into one png?

Comment: What sorts of things have you tried to see if you can do it? The above sample code that you copied from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810209/xcode-save-a-pdf-as-image) doesn't tell us a whole lot about what your problem is.

Comment: I have used the Code from the slide that is right. First I Download a PDF file from the web and Save it to local documents then i will Convention this PDF to png for the reason to post this on eg. Facebook with the uiactivityview. This Workshop Perfect, but only the First Page of the PDF will be converted to png and Not the whole PDF. Or is there Apotheke Way to Share the current PDF file from uiwebview with the uiactivityview?