# How to save PDF to images on OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf

Is  there a way to save PDF pages to images on OS X by Xcode 5? I have searched on Stackoverflow and found this [Xcode save a PDF as Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810209/xcode-save-a-pdf-as-image)

However it is for iOS, not OS X. I want to export PDF pages to images like JPG or PNG etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToUrPDF];    
NSPDFImageRep *pdfImg = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSInteger pageCount = [pdfImg pageCount];
for(int i = 0 ; i < pageCount ; i++) {
    [pdfImg setCurrentPage:i];
    NSImage *temp = [[NSImage alloc] init];
    [temp addRepresentation:pdfImg];
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[temp TIFFRepresentation]];
    NSData *finalData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
    NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%ld.jpg", (long)[pdfImg currentPage]];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"pathWrUWantToSave", pageName] contents:finalData attributes:nil];
}
```

Comment: Dear Shanti K, could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626526/how-to-convert-pdf-to-nsimage-and-change-the-dpi